# Internet DNS problems - Changing DNS doesn't seem to work

Tags: networking, dns, 22.04

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, connecting works fine on my home network but never properly connects on my school's network which utilizes MSCHAPv2. Using `ping` with an IP address works fine, but using "google.com" for example doesn't. Changing the DNS like I've seen solve the problem for others doesn't seem to do anything to help.

Edit: For some reason I was missing the `resolvconf` package, installing it on my home network appears to fix the problem.